# putty 上で認識されるキーボード配列が気づいたら英字配列になっている

Tags: windows, ubuntu, putty

OS: Windows 7

PuTTY(0.66) 上で、 ubuntu14.04 に接続して、いくつかの作業を行っていると、気づいたら受け付けられている入力が、英字キーボート配列を想定した動きになっています。気づいたら、というのは、最初は問題なく入力できていて、「半角・全角」キーによって日本語入力も問題なく行えているのですが、ふと気づいたときには、日本語入力はもちろん、各記号系の入力がおかしくなっていてます。 (たとえば：本来の`+`入力が`:`になったり、`:`入力が`'`入力になったり)

http://www.h4.dion.ne.jp/~hanbei/keyb.htm

をみた結果、おそらく私のキーボードは JP106 (のスーパーセット) であるが、問題の挙動時には US101 の配列として認識されている様子でした。

これに陥った場合、 putty を再起動すれば、ひとまず症状はリセットされますが、わりと不便なのでどうにかしたいと考えています。

質問:

- この挙動を防ぐ方法ありますでしょうか。
- ある場合、どうしたらいいでしょうか
- ない場合、どこが悪さをしてこうなっているのでしょうか。

追記@2016/03/02:
OS 再起動したら再現しなくなりました。再現条件がイマイチわからない…

追記@2016/03/02:
問題の挙動をしているときには、 Windows の言語バーが「EN」に変化していることに気づきました。どのタイミングでこの変化が発生しているのかは、引き続き調査中。

Comment: 気付かず ALT-SHIFT を押しているという事はないでしょうか？

Comment: @mattn それは、どういうことでしょうか。  キーボード上の、 alt や shift が私が気づいていないだけで、押された結果、入力が shift ないし、 alt した結果になっている、ということでしょうか。

Comment: @YukiInoue Windowsのデフォルト設定で、Alt+Shiftが入力言語の切り替えに割り当てられているのです。ただWin7であれば、ご自身で入力言語に英語を追加しない限り、このキーを押しても切り替わることはないように思います（Win8だと追加しなくても切り替えられるのではまるのです・・・）。

Comment: @mattn 原因は Alt + Shift でした。 Windows 7 ですけど、この挙動になっていました。。

Comment: タスクバーの設定で、 Alt + Shift をとられないように設定すると、解決しました。

Comment: @YukiInoue 解決したのであればその内容を自分で「回答」にしてください

Answer (score 3, accepted):

問題は、 @mattn さんと @unarist さんが指摘していた通り、 `Alt+Shift` が、 Windows OS の言語切り替えのショートカットキーとして利用されているからでした。

言語バー(と、言うのでしょうか、自信はないですが、、)の設定 -> 詳細なキー設定 で、「入力言語を切り替える」のホットキーを無効にすることで、問題は解決しました。